# Getting content type as "application/octet-stream" even if iam not uploading any image

Tags: java, php, image, forms

Hi in my application i have a form which contains image uploading functionality and in my controller i have kept validation like

```
       File f = getUpload();
       if(f != null) {
               if (!getUploadContentType().matches("^image/.*png|image/.*gif|image/.*jpeg|image/.*bmp|image/.*tiff$") {
          return FAILED;
           }
      }
```

if i upload an image and submit form i get getUploadContentType() type as image/jpeg and works fine and in case if i dont upload the image and submit form i am not getting File "**f**" as null and if i see getUploadContentType() iam getting like **application/octet-stream** so iam not understanding why iam not getting null even if iam not uploading image and here my requirement is to submit form event if i donot upload image

Here is my form code (minimized code it contains huge code)

```
<s:form name="updateProfile" id="updateProfile" action="/user/updateMyProfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <input name="upload" class="file" type="file" size="30" style="cursor: pointer;"/> 
<div class="pull-right m-b-lg m-r-xs"> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-search m-r-llg" >Save changes</button> <a href="#">cancel</a> 
</div> 
</s:form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML form?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here. The `getUploadContentType` (of the form) will of course never be something like `image/.*png`. It will be binary first. Then you write the file to disk and get it's content type. `application/octet-stream` just says: "it's binary".

Comment: No if iam uploading an image and see getUploadContentType iam able to see content type as jpeg|image my doubt is if i dont upload any image and submit the form why iam not getting my file variable "f" as null and instead i get content type like application/octet-stream